# change browser go back event in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to detect the back function in the browser and need to redirect to a different page using vue js. My attempt is as below.

```
mounted: function () {
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/register"
      });
   };
}
```

But it will not identify $router and saying it's not a function. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the function is not instance of vue component so it will not work. Try this code:

```
  mounted: function () {
    window.onpopstate = (event) => {
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/register"
      });
   };
```